# Why can't Emacs on Mac OS X find the Info directory node?

Tags: linux, macos, emacs

The default [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) on Mac OS X, 22.1, appears to have some problems with the info/help stuff.

When you hit `C+h i`, it says:

> Can't find the Info directory node.

It works in AquaEmacs, but I downloaded the 23 version of emacs [precompiled binaries from here](http://emacsformacosx.com/)  and I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Two steps to the solution:

1. Find where the *info* pages are
2. Put this in your .emacs: `(add-to-list 'Info-default-directory-list "/path/to/your/info")`

You can find the GNU Emacs (related) manuals here: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/

Follow the link into which manual you want and you'll find a gzipped info version of it.  Download, uncompress, and adjust the `"/path/to/your/info"` to point to that directory.

Comment: is step 2 to be done in the .emacs file, i assume? looks like lisp

Comment: @Scott Yes, add #2 to your .emacs.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth noting that when you hit <kbd>C-h i</kbd> emacs will try to find the directory node. Which is a file called `dir` in your info directory. The file on my system has this written at the head of it which explains:

> This is the file .../info/dir, which
>   contains the topmost node of the Info
>   hierarchy, called (dir)Top. The first
>   time you invoke Info you start off
>   looking at this node.

It is basically a directory of all of your info files, you can add nodes to it as you install them, here is a snippet of the file on my system:

```
* Menu:

* Info: (info).         How to use the documentation browsing system.

Emacs
* Emacs: (emacs).       The extensible self-documenting text editor.
* Emacs FAQ: (efaq).    Frequently Asked Questions about Emacs.
```